# how to set credentials to use GCP API from Dataproc instance

Tags: google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-dataproc

I am trying to access some credentials stored in google Secret Manager. To access this its required to have credentials setup in the Cluster machine where the jar is running.

I have SSH into the master instance, and seen there is nothing configured for `GOOGLE_APPLICATION_CREDENTIALS`.

I am curious to know how to assign `GOOGLE_APPLICATION_CREDENTIALS` or any other alternative that allows to use GCP APIs that require credentials.

Answer (score 1):

If you are running on Dataproc clusters, default GCE service account should be already configured for you. Assuming your clusters are running outside GCP environment, in that case you want to follow this [instruction](https://cloud.google.com/docs/authentication/production#manually) to manually set up a service account that has editor/owner role for Google Secret Manager, and download the credential key file and point `GOOGLE_APPLICATION_CREDENTIALS`  to it.